# where react SWR or query save his data and where I can see it?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I understand it's save on cache but i can't find it or how and where react query save his data
I want to understand how it works and how I can see where its save the data because I can't see it in the devtools or any other place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use SWR and it stores the cache in [an instance](https://github.com/vercel/swr/blob/master/src/config.ts#L11) of the [Cache class](https://github.com/vercel/swr/blob/master/src/cache.ts).I didn't find a way to see it in devtools though.

React query seems to use a similar approach, I mean, the cache is stored in a global variable, but it has [his own devtools](https://react-query.tanstack.com/docs/devtools). The documentation explains [how it works with more details](https://react-query.tanstack.com/docs/guides/caching) and it even allows you to set [your own cache provider](https://react-query.tanstack.com/docs/api#reactquerycacheprovider).